# How can I solve this logic question using propositional logic (Natural deduction)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

$$\big((P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P\big) \rightarrow P$$

I need to solve this using simple natural deduction rules

these can be hypothesis, $\rightarrow$ intro, $\rightarrow$ elim, conj and disjunct intro and elim, and negation intro (Reductio ad absurdum) and negation elimination (Double)

Comment: What are your own thoughts on this problem? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: Can you use $A\to B \equiv \neg A \lor B$? If so, start with the hypothesis $((P\to Q)\to Q$, then apply this definition to obtain $(\neg P \lor Q) \to P)$. Then introduce the hypothesis $\neg P$ and obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

1) $\big((P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P\big)$ --- assumed [a]

2) $\lnot P$ --- assumed [b]

3) $P$ --- assumed [c]

4) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 3)

5) $Q$ --- from 4) by [ex falso quodlibet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_explosion) (i.e. : $\bot \vdash \varphi$) or directly from 2) and 3) (skipping 4)) by [negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_for_classical_sentential_calculus) (i.e. : $\varphi, ¬ \varphi \vdash \psi$)

6) $P \to Q$ --- from 3) and 5) by $\to$-intro, discharging [c]

7) $P$ --- from 1) and 6) by $\to$-elim

8) $\bot$ --- from 2) and 7)

9) $P$ --- from 2) and 8) by [double negation elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_negation#Double_negative_elimination), discharging [b]

> 10) $\vdash \big((P\rightarrow Q)\rightarrow P\big) \rightarrow P$ --- from 1) and 9) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

The use of *double negation elimination* is unavoidable, because [Peirce's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peirce%27s_law) is not *intuitionistically* valid.

Comment: Does (5) use one of the allowed rules/axioms?

Comment: I didn't know that was the Principle of Explosion. Thanks for the link. I have been calling it the Arbitrary Consequent Rule. Anyway, this was not listed by the OP as an allowable rule.

Comment: @DanChristensen - the rules for negation in Natural Deduction changes according if we use $\lnot$ as primitive or defined in terms of $\bot$. In the first case, in place of *EFQ* we can use directly [Negation Elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rules_of_inference#Rules_for_classical_sentential_calculus) : $\varphi, \lnot \varphi \vdash \psi$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the antecedent.  Assume the negation of the consequent.  Assume the antecedent of the antecedent of the antecedent.  Assume the negation of the consequent of the antecedent of the antecedent.  Derive a contradiction.  Infer the negation of the negation of the consequent of the antecedent of the antecedent.  Infer the consequent of the antecedent of the antecedent.  Infer the antecedent of the antecedent.  Infer the consequent of the antecedent.  Infer a contradiction.  Infer the negation of the negation of the desired formula.  Infer the desired formula.

Anytime you have a formula like (($\alpha$ $\rightarrow$ $\beta$) $\rightarrow$ $\gamma$), you might see if you can assume $\alpha$ and then derive $\beta$.  Then you can infer ($\alpha$ $\rightarrow$ $\beta$) and then infer $\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked Mauro's answer on the [forall x proof builder and checker](https://the21stcenturymonads.net/forallx/).

Here are two useful links: [summary document](https://the21stcenturymonads.net/forallx/forallx-rules.pdf), [Calgary remix](http://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Erzach/static/forallx/forallxyyc.pdf).

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is a LaTeX transcription:

$01\ \square\ ((P\to Q)\to P)$

$02\ \square\ \square\ \lnot P$

$03\ \square\ \square\ \square\ P$

$04\ \square\ \square\ \square\ \bot\qquad\bot$I 2,3

$05\ \square\ \square\ \square\ Q\qquad\bot$E 4

$06\ \square\ \square\ P\to Q\qquad\to$I 3-5

$07\ \square\ \square\ P\qquad\to$E 1,6

$08\ \square\ \square\ \bot\qquad\bot$I 2,7

$09\ \square\ \neg\neg P\qquad\neg$I 2-8

$10\ \square\ P\qquad$DNE 9

$11\ (P\to Q)\to P)\to P\qquad\to$I 1-10