# Natural Deduction stuck

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction

$$\vdash (( p → q) →  p) →  p$$ how would I go about solving this with no premises. to get the implication i know i need $$(p → q) →  p$$ as my first assumption but im stuck to where to go from there

Comment: You can see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1545970/how-can-i-solve-this-logic-question-using-propositional-logic-natural-deduction).

Comment: You can't prove this in natural deduction without using the law of the excluded middle.  If you *can* use LEM, then every propositional formula becomes trivial, just apply LEM to every propositional variable, work out the cases, and use Or Elimination to combine the cases into a final result.

Answer (score 0):

First hint: Prove ($\lnot$p$\rightarrow$(p$\rightarrow$q)) as a lemma.

More detailed analysis:

1. What is the goal?

The goal is to produce to (((p $\rightarrow$ q) $\rightarrow$ p) $\rightarrow$ p).

2. What evidence do you have so far?

You have evidence that if you assume ((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$p) and produce p, that a solution can get constructed.

3. If you assume something, what is the structure of that assumption?

The assumption ((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$p), has the structure such that (p$\rightarrow$q) is the antecedent and p is the consequent.  Thus, if you can produce (p$\rightarrow$q), by detachment ("modus ponens"), you can deduce p.

4. Can you assume anything and get rid of that assumption?

Suppose you assume ((p$\rightarrow$q)$\rightarrow$p).  You want 'p'.  But, let's say your enemy says that obtaining 'p' is impossible.  So, let's assume your enemy correct, and thus assume that $\lnot$p makes sense.  Can you then obtain 'p' under that assumption, with the analysis of 3. in mind?

Answer (score -1):

I just did it with a truth table. Set p to each of 0 and 1 (false and true), and set q to each of 0 and 1 as well. That gives you 4 combinations of the two. Then, work your way from the inside out.

> Case 1: $p = 0$, $q = 0$

$p→q = 1$

$1→p=0$

$0→p=1$

> Case 2: $p = 0$, $q = 1$

$p→q = 1$

$1→p=0$

$0→p=1$

> Case 3: $p = 1$, $q = 0$

$p→q = 0$

$0→p=1$

$1→p=1$

> Case 4: $p = 1$, $q = 1$

$p→q = 1$

$1→p=1$

$1→p=1$

Therefore the statement holds true for every case.

Comment: I need to use natural deduction ):